# Python re.sub() does not perform any substitution if used within function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-re

I've been trying to use regular expressions to clean some .txt files contained in a local folder, but the script performs no modifications on my string variables. The original content I need to modify is something like "words words wor-\r\nds words words wo-\r\n\r\n\r\nrds"; I need to remove any line-final hyphens and all returns + new line.

The function works fine up until line `7` (it seems to correctly accesses a sample file and print its contents as a string), but when I apply `re.sub` to it (line `8`) and inspect my modified variable (line `9`), the script still returns the unmodified string. However, if I define `txt_contents` as a separate variable and use `re.sub` on it, it actually does perform the modifications that I expect. What am I doing wrong? Should I even need to define `txt_clean` within the function? I have a list of substitutions to perform on these same files and would prefer not to re-define my variable for each one. Thanks in advance!

```
1 def clean_files(dir):
2    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
3        for file in files:
4            with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as txt_file:
5                txt_contents = txt_file.read()
6                print(txt_contents) # OK
7                print(type(txt_contents)) # correctly returns "str"
8                txt_clean = re.sub('-(\r\n)+', '', txt_contents)
9                print(txt_clean) # still returns the same text
```

Comment: You're a bit unclear.  Is the above code giving you the right answer or the wrong answer?  What is the alternative version of your code?  You do understand that `re.sub` returns a new string and doesn't modify the string passed as an argument, right?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I'll try to explain better. The code was giving me the wrong answer: I wanted `txt_clean` to contain the new string returned by applying `re.sub` on `txt_contents`. From the comment below, I understood that my regex was wrong: from `txt_clean = re.sub('-(\r\n)+', '', txt_contents)` I removed `\r` and now the script is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python will by default change your newlines, when you read a file in text mode. Look at [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and how you can change that with parameter `newline`. If you want newlines unchanged, I think you have to read the file in binary mode.